# Issue converting

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm beginner in using Python as Data Scientist. I'm working on a project but I couldn't go further than this stage.
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '506 Harmony Ln'

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

## Add these lines to turn off the warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Segragate dataset into train and test
train = data.drop(['price', 'date'], axis=1)

test = data['price']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, test, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

regr = LinearRegression()

regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '506 Harmony Ln'
```

link to the data:
https://www.kaggle.com/shree1992/housedata

Thanks

Comment: Before you fit your model all string values need to converted into numeric i.e, 1 and 0, then only can perform. Create **Dummy Variables**

Comment: Refer to my [Notebook](https://github.com/anmolparida/data_science_python/blob/master/Linear%20Regression/Car%20Price%20Analysis%20-%20Geely%20Auto/Car%20Price%20Analysis%20-%20Linear%20Regression.ipynb) for **Dummy Variable Creation**.